# File.Exists not working on network drive

Tags: c#, file-io, scheduled-tasks, console-application

My console app checks for the presence of a file on a network drive and logs a message when it does not exist. Today I deployed my app to a QA machine and File.Exists() has been returning false for files that do exist. I am running the app via windows task scheduler. When I ran it from the command line it seems to work fine. But either way I don't trust it now. Has anyone seen this behavior or have any insight?:

```
Using System.IO;

private static void Main()
{
    var fileName = @"x:\folder\file1.txt"; //be a network share
    If (!File.Exists(fileName) 
    {
        LogMessage("File is not on disk.");
    }
    else
    {
        LogMessage("File is on disk.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Drive letter mappings are a per-user setting.  So standard failure mode is running the scheduled task with the wrong user account.

Comment: I ran it under my account which does have that drive mapped, and it still didn't work. Can you explain "standard failure mode" and why I must use a unc path (which fixed the issue).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that the drives are not mapped when running from task scheduler.  Try a UNC path

```
var fileName = @"\\server\share\folder\file1.txt";
```

Comment: Careful--I've given up on using File.Exists with UNC paths--it was eternally returning false on files that do exist.

Comment: I wanted to quickly verify that the above answer is correct, so I created a test app that used both ways, ran it under the scheduler... and on the file I used both ways are returning true. I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: Thank you, dsolimano. I added the unc path to my real application and it seems to be working fine. And it has nothing to do with the task scheduler from what I can tell.  But can someone explain why the other way doesn't work? Why does File.Exist require a UNC path to be accurate? I am just curious about the lower-level details.

Comment: @inspectorGadget in my experience it's been because the drive mappings aren't present when running from Task Scheduler, either for my own account or for another user's account, unless you run a login script manually to map them.

Comment: Thanks. If I made this app a windows service running under a specific account, do you think it would work?

Comment: Only if you mapped the drives before running the application, or perhaps if group policy mapped the drives https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770902.aspx

Comment: We might be running into a race conditions situation using file exists on a network share.  Seems to be returning false when a file exists but not always.  It also returns true some of the time.  I am seeing alot of SO posts that are not recommending using file.exists, however we may need to set up a loop until the file exists..